# Saving values from .map function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was able to retrieve the data from database using .map function. But I'm having a problem saving the values of the selected data from the .map. How can I save the values from a .map function? The values that I need to save are the values of the buttons that uses .map function.

```
    export class CreateInspectDtl extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
        className: "buttonTrue",
        selectedByCode: [],
        categButton:[],
        categ: [],
        selected: 'All',
        categData: []
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
    }
    changeColor(itemSelected, itemSelectedTestCode) {
        try {
        let selectedByCode = [...this.state.selectedByCode];
        const findSelectedCodeIndex = selectedByCode.findIndex(
            item => item.test_code === itemSelectedTestCode
        );
        if (findSelectedCodeIndex === -1) {
            const newSelectedByObject = {
            test_code: itemSelectedTestCode,
            selected_test_line_ids: [itemSelected.test_line_id]
            };
            this.setState({
            selectedByCode: [...selectedByCode, newSelectedByObject]
            });
        } else {
            const selecteCodeObject = selectedByCode[findSelectedCodeIndex];
            selectedByCode[findSelectedCodeIndex] = {
            ...selecteCodeObject,
            selected_test_line_ids: [itemSelected.test_line_id]
            };
            this.setState({
            selectedByCode
            });
        }
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
    }
    getHostname(){
        const protocol = window.location.protocol;
        const hostname = window.location.hostname;
        const result = protocol + "//" + hostname;
        return result;
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ selected: event.target.value });
        const qa_testcateg_id = event.target.value;
        const comp_id = localStorage.getItem('comp_id');
        const div_id = localStorage.getItem('div_id');
        const compid = comp_id.replace(/"/g, '');
        const divid = div_id.replace(/"/g, '');
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: this.getHostname()+'/inspection/src/components/php/getCategData.php',
            data: 'qa_testcateg_id='+qa_testcateg_id+'&comp_id='+compid+'&div_id='+divid,
            config: 
            {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                Accept: "application/json"
            }} 
            })
            .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ categData: data })
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }

    routeChange = (path) =>  {
        this.props.history.push(path);
    }
    renderOptions() {
        return this.state.categ.map((categs) => {
        return (
            <option
                label={categs.testcateg_code}
                value={categs.qa_testcateg_id}
                key={categs.qa_testcateg_id}>{categs.testcateg_code}
            </option>
        );
        });
    } 
    render() {
        var changeClass = this.state.className;
        var click = this.changeColor;
        var selectedByCode = this.state.selectedByCode;
        var categData = this.state.categData.map(data => {
            return (
            <div key={data.test_code}>
                <ButtonGroup>
                <p
                    style={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    marginTop: "0.7vmin",
                    marginBottom: "0"
                    }}
                >
                    {data.test_code}
                </p>
                {data.test_line.map(test => {
                    var selectedCode = selectedByCode.length && selectedByCode.find(item => item.test_code === data.test_code);
                    var itemSelected = selectedCode && selectedCode.selected_test_line_ids.includes(test.test_line_id);
                    var text_range = test.text_range;
                    console.log(test, itemSelected);
                    return (
                    <div>
                        <ButtonTest
                        isSelected={itemSelected}
                        className={changeClass}
                        onClick={test => click(test, data.test_code)}
                        test={test}
                        value={text_range => test.text_range}
                        />
                    </div>
                    );
                })}
                </ButtonGroup>
                <center>
                <div style={{width:'60%'}}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                    <textarea style={{marginTop: "0.7em",width: "33.5em",height: "5em",align: "center"}}></textarea>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                </div>
                </center>
                <br />
            </div>
            );
        });
        return (
        <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div>
                <div>
                {categData}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <center>
                <RaisedButton label="Save Page and Continue" primary={true} onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} />
                </center>
            </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
        );
    }
    handleClick = event =>  {
        event.preventDefault();
        const model = localStorage.getItem('model');
        const color= localStorage.getItem('color');
        const engine = localStorage.getItem('engine');
        const vin = localStorage.getItem('vin');
        const cs_num = localStorage.getItem('cs_code');
        const user_id =localStorage.getItem('user_id');
        const comp_id = localStorage.getItem('comp_id');
        const div_id = localStorage.getItem('div_id');
        const inspect_code = localStorage.getItem('inspect_code');
        const modeldata = model.replace(/"/g, '');
        const colordata = color.replace(/"/g, '');
        const enginedata = engine.replace(/"/g, '');
        const vin_code = vin.replace(/"/g, '');    
        const userid = user_id.replace(/"/g, '');
        const cs_no = cs_num.replace(/"/g, '');
        const compid = comp_id.replace(/"/g, '');
        const divid = div_id.replace(/"/g, '');
        const inspectcode = inspect_code.replace(/"/g, '');

        axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: this.getHostname()+'/inspection/src/components/php/save_inspection.php',
        data: 'model_code='+modeldata+'&color_code='+colordata+'&engine_code='+enginedata+'&vin_code='+vin_code+'&cs_no='+cs_no+'&user_id='+userid+'&cs_no='+cs_no+'&comp_id='+compid+'&div_id='+divid+'&inspect_code='+inspectcode,
        config: 
        {
            headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Accept: "application/json"
        }}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            localStorage.setItem('inspect_id', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            window.location = "/continueinspect"
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response)
        });
    }
    }
    class ButtonTest extends Component  {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    }
    render() {
    var className = this.props.className;
    // console.log(this.props.test);
    return (
    <center>
        <div style={{width:'55%'}}>
        <center>
        <Button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.test)} className={this.props.isSelected ? 'buttonTrue' : 'buttonFalse'}>
            {this.props.value(this.props.text_range)}
        </Button>
        </center>
        </div>
    </center>
    )
    }}
    export default CreateInspectDtl;
```

As you can see there are two compenents we used to retrieve and be able to change the color of the buttons.